Find a linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that its range is $x+y+z=0$
This exercise is very similar to this one. However, I don't have any info about the kernel.
My question is: how could I find the third vector to find associate it with $e_3$? I mean, it's clear that
$$T(e_1)=(1,-1,0)$$
$$T(e_2)=(1,0,-1)$$
that came from $x=-y-z$. But I don't know how to find the vector $v$ such that
$$T(e_3)=v$$

How can a rather arbitrary assignment be "clear"? You could just as well have swapped the values, or multiplied on by $\pi$, or taken $T(e_1)$ to be $(2, -1, -1)$, or... Also, you should probably ask yourself what the dimension of the range is.

The (perhaps) surprising answer is: pick any vector $v = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$ such that $v_1+v_2+v_3=0$, and assign $T(e_3)=v$.
Why does this work?
First of all, you might be aware that $x+y+z=0$ defines a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. Let me denote this subspace $V \subset \mathbb R^3$, that is,
$$V = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x_1+x_2+x_3=0\}
$$
Second of all, you might be aware that $T(e_1)=(1,-1,0)$ and $T(e_2)=(1,0,-1)$ already span the subspace $V$. From this you can conclude that no matter what you pick for $v$, you have
$$V \subset \text{range}(T)
$$
Third, picking $v$ as suggested above, automatically $v \in V$, and so $T(e_3) \in V$, and so
$$\text{range}(T) \subset V
$$
Putting these together, it follows that $\text{range}(T)=V$.
